# Embed Slippy Map in tkinter/python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, openstreetmap

I am looking for a ability to generate/embed a slippy map (i.e. OpenStreetMaps) into a Tkinter Application that I can then plot geodetic coordinates and elliptical data over it (coming from a pyodbc connection to an *.mdb file). The user needs the geographic information (city name, etc.) for more efficient analysis.

I've looked at mapnik, Leaflet, pyrender, TileMill, TileStache, et al to facilitate this pipe dream and none really seem to fit the bill. The data needs to be interactive (balloon info, select-able, etc.) and dynamic (update when new user-defined sql parses data for filtering). The reason being, the other half of this program is ran through Tkinter and MatPlotLib. A complete system overhaul is what I'm trying to avoid.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Some of my code available below:

(I apologize in advance for any errors or idiocies. I've only been writing in python for the last 3 months...all self taught)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from pylab import *
import tkMessageBox as mb
import pyodbc
import sys
import ttk

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

def connect_db():
    global c
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s' % filename)
    c = conn.cursor()

def query_db():
    global time
    global freq
    global pri
    global pw
    freq=[]
    time=[]
    pri = []
    pw = []

c.execute("SELECT utc_usec_time_stamp, freq_mhz, pri, pw FROM SampleData")
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    time.append(row[0])
    freq.append(row[1])
    pri.append(row[2])
    pw.append(row[3])
    progressbar.step(0.0008)
    root.update_idletasks()

def plot(): 
    global sb1
    global sb2
    global sb3
    global canvas

    f = Figure()
    f.clf()
    f.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05,top=0.98,left=0.08,right=0.98,hspace=0.1)
    sb1 = f.add_subplot(3,1,1)
    sb1.scatter(time,freq)
    setp(sb1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    sb1.set_ylabel("FREQ (MHz)")

    sb2 = f.add_subplot(3,1,2, sharex=sb1)  
    sb2.scatter(time,pri)   
    setp(sb2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    sb2.set_ylabel("PRI (usec)")

    sb3 = f.add_subplot(3,1,3, sharex=sb1)  
    sb3.scatter(time,pw)    
    setp(sb3.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    sb3.set_xlabel("TIME")
    sb3.set_ylabel("PW (usec)")

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)

    logo.pack_forget()

    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def test():
    global pri

    p = Tk.Toplevel(root)
    f = Tk.Frame(p)
    f.pack(side="top")
    f.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    f.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
    lbl = Tk.Label(f, text="label")
    lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
    e = Tk.Entry(f)
    e.grid(row=1, column=2)
    b = Tk.Button(f, text="Button")
    b.grid(row=1, column=3)
    lbl2 = Tk.Label(f, text=" ")
    lbl2.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=100)

    fig = Figure()
    sb1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    sb1.hist(pri)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=p)

    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, p )
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def __init__(): 
    global root
    global rmi
    global rma
    global prmi
    global prma
    global pwmi
    global pwma
    global pdf
    global progressbar
    global tf
    global logo

    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("Airborne Tactical Analysis System (ATLAS)")
    root.wm_state('zoomed')

    menubar = Tk.Menu(root)
    File = Tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    File.add_command(label="Open", command=open)
    File.add_separator()
    File.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)
    Options = Tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    Options.add_command(label="-Coming Soon-")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=Options)
    PlotData = Tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    PlotData.add_command(label="FREQ v PW")
    PlotData.add_command(label="FREQ v PRI")
    PlotData.add_command(label="PRI v PW")
    PlotData.add_command(label="FREQ HISTOGRAM")
    PlotData.add_command(label="PRI HISTOGRAM", command=test)
    PlotData.add_command(label="PW HISTOGRAM")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Plot Data", menu=PlotData)
    Geo = Tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    Geo.add_command(label="Generate Map")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Geo", menu=Geo)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    pdf = Tk.Frame(borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
    pdf.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    pdf.grid_rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
    pdf.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    tf = Tk.Frame(borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
    tf.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    progl = Tk.Label(text=" Processing: ")
    progl.pack(in_=tf, side="left", ipady=10)
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient='horizontal', length=200, mode='determinate')
    progressbar.pack(in_=tf, side="left")
    fl = Tk.Label(text="Current File:")
    fl.pack(in_=tf, side="left", ipadx=10)

    b1 = Tk.Button(pdf, text="Submit", command=filter_builder)
    b1.grid(in_=pdf, row=2, columnspan=3, pady=10)

    buf = Tk.Label(text="   ")
    mil = Tk.Label(text="MIN")
    mal = Tk.Label(text="MAX")
    rfl = Tk.Label(text="RF:")
    pwl = Tk.Label(text="PW:")
    prl = Tk.Label(text="PRI:")
    prmi = Tk.Entry()
    prma = Tk.Entry()
    pwmi = Tk.Entry()
    pwma = Tk.Entry()
    rmi = Tk.Entry()
    rma = Tk.Entry()
    buf.grid(in_=pdf, column=3,row=3)
    mil.grid(in_=pdf, column=1,row=3, pady=4)
    mal.grid(in_=pdf, column=2,row=3)
    rfl.grid(in_=pdf, column=0,row=4)
    rmi.grid(in_=pdf, column=1,row=4)
    rma.grid(in_=pdf, column=2,row=4)
    prl.grid(in_=pdf, column=0,row=5)
    prmi.grid(in_=pdf, column=1,row=5)
    prma.grid(in_=pdf, column=2,row=5)
    pwl.grid(in_=pdf, column=0,row=6)
    pwmi.grid(in_=pdf, column=1,row=6)
    pwma.grid(in_=pdf, column=2,row=6)

    photo = Tk.PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

    logo = Tk.Label(image=photo)
    logo.image = photo
    logo.pack(side="top", fill="both", pady=100)

    root.mainloop()

__init__()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after much research and tinkering (reads: late nights and frustrations) I've finally devised the best way to do this:

1) Utilizing [mplleaflet](https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet), which plays off of matplotlib's plotting abilities to render the data points over a slippy map. This is my front-end (API).

2) I stumbled upon [python-mbtiles](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-mbtiles) on GitHub that actually fit the bill of serving *.mbtiles png data offline through Tornado. I manipulated the mplleaflet's urls to point to my localhost port where Tornado was serving the tiles to render.

3) After accomplishing both, I realized that Tkinter cannot parse html in any way, so I ended up scrapping it all together and using the much more powerful PySide as it contains the QWebKit that I used to contain it in my GUI rather than an actual web browser window.

All in all, a very long but enlightening process. I hope others may learn from this as well.

Comment: This was a very helpful post to me. I was wondering if you could share some of your code, even though this was from over 2 years ago.

Comment: A lions share of my code is at my [ATLAS repository](https://github.com/riebecj/ATLAS) on GitHub. Although, I will point out that the whole project has be deprecated and scrapped.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is an old question, but if somebody wants to have an interactive OpenStreetMap map inside their application, I wrote a library called TkinterMapView to display tile based maps like OpenStreetMap or Google-Maps inside of Tkinter:

**Documentation: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/TkinterMapView**

**Install: `pip3 install tkintermapview`**

You just create a TkinterMapView widget like you create a frame or a button and you have an interactive map, where you can also set position markers or a path. You can focus the map on a specific location with coordinates or by passing an address string to the widget like in the following example:

```py
import tkinter
from tkintermapview import TkinterMapView

root_tk = tkinter.Tk()
root_tk.geometry(f"{600}x{400}")
root_tk.title("map_view_simple_example.py")

# create map widget
map_widget = TkinterMapView(root_tk, width=600, height=400, corner_radius=0)
map_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

map_widget.set_address("Berlin Germany", marker=True)

root_tk.mainloop()
```

The above code will give you the following window:

[image]